# Usar java para conectar no WebService Magento API SOAP v1?

Tags: java, web-service, magento

No site oficial, http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/introduction.html, tem uma citação que fala que o java é mais compatível ao usar a soap v2:

> As of v1.3, you may also use the following URL to access the Magento API v2, which has been added to improve compatibility with Java and .NET:

Tentei usar a v1 com java, mas ao compilar no terminal este projeto [`magento-java`](https://github.com/webdevwilson/magento-java) utilizando maven (`mvn install`, ou `mvn package`) me retorna estes dois erros:

```
[ERROR] /magento-java/src/main/java/com/magi/magento/service/BaseService.java:[27,34] cannot find symbol

[ERROR] /magento-java/src/main/java/com/magi/magento/service/OrderService.java:[112,44] incompatible types
```

Vi que tem uma 2ª opção de usar java para conectar com o web service que é o `magja`: http://code.google.com/p/magja/

Qual é  o recomendado para integrar no java? No php é facil, mas java complica a situação.

Outra coisa, quero usar no v1 mesmo (`/pastaMagento/index.php/api/soap/?wsdl`) para conectar com meu WS usando java, qual a melhor maneira e como devo fazer isso?

Comment: Você quer contruir o projeto `magento-java` ou qualquer solução para consumir o WS tá valendo?

Comment: desde que seja em java , é o ponto principal. Tentei usar o SoapUI versão 5.2.0 agora pra autenticar mas não vai